# How to import/read a .dbf file on sqlserver 2012 using openrowset?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-foxpro, dbf

I have too many free tables from an old software and need to connect some of this tables to sql to tranfer the info and use in other software.

Comment: Have you tried the import/export wizard in the SQL Server program files group of the start menu?

Comment: yes but it does not work :(
it says TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard

Feature is not available. (Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro)

Comment: You might  read this How to Convert DBF to XLS     https://smallbusiness.chron.com/convert-dbf-xls-55554.html

Comment: @donPablo, FWIW the information in the link you provided is not correct. Excel cannot read "any" DBF file (unless it uses VFPOLEDB driver). Particularly File\dBase files wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

While your question is about how to do that using OpenRowSet, I would say forget about getting VFP data using OpenRowset or OpenQuery (which would be better of the two). Probably 32 bits or 64 bits import\export wizards wouldn't work either. All those were working successfully in good old times before windows 10 at least. I don't know what they have changed, now they all fail (I had tons of working OpenRowset, OpenQuery samples under windows 7).
You might try Sybase ADS driver with OpenRowset and OpenQuery.

Fortunately there are many workarounds. Some workarounds use intermediates like access and excel but IMHO they are overkill.

If you are using VFP itself, simplest would be to do this from within VFP, where it is a series of "auto generated on the fly" code executing against SQL Server.

One other option (which I favor) would be to use some C# code, that would do the transfer using "SqlBulkCopy" class. For a generic solution, you could:

- Create a database on server,
- Read a VFP table's Schema information,
- Create compatible table on server (meaning you might want to change datatypes),
- Create column mappings info,
- Bulk load to table
- Repeat the process in a loop for all tables.

Here is one sample that doesn't read the schema but instead creates a temp table on server with a known schema and sample mapping just for demo purposes (if you think DBF to SQL Server tools on the market are over 100$ not a bad starter):

```
void Main()
{
  string sqlConnectionString = @"server=.\SQLExpress;Trusted_Connection=yes;Database=Test";
  string path = @"C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL FOXPRO 9\SAMPLES\Northwind";

  DataTable tbl = new DataTable(); // just to show the results - sadece sonuclari gostermek icin

  using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source="+path))
  using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection( sqlConnectionString ))
  {
    // Creatint a temp SQL Server table for sampling.
    // If the table already existed then this part wouldn't exist.
    // We would simply insert then.

    // gecici bir SQL server tablosu yaratiyoruz ornek icin.
    // tablo zaten var ise bu kisim olmayacak. Sadece insert edecektik.

    SqlCommand createTemp = new SqlCommand();
    createTemp.CommandText = @"create table ##SqlBulkSample 
    (
      [CustomerId] char(6), 
      [Company] varchar(50), 
      [Contact] varchar(50), 
      [Country] varchar(20) 
    )"; 
    createTemp.Connection = scn;

    scn.Open();
    createTemp.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Get the data from VFP and write to server using SqlBulkCopy

    // Excelden veriyi al ve SqlBulkCopy ile servera yaz  
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select CustomerId, CompanyName, ContactName, Country from Customers", cn);
    SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(scn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock,null);

    // For demonstration purposes of column mapping, 
    // we have different count of fields with different field names and order.
    // Without mapping, it would be a copy of the same structured data

    // Column mapping'i orneklemek icin farkli sayi, isim ve sirada alanlarimiz var.
    // Mapping olmasa idi ayni yapidaki veri kopyalaniyor olacakti.
    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(0,"[CustomerId]");
    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(1,"[Company]");
    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(2,"[Contact]");
    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(3,"[Country]");

    cn.Open();
    OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    //SqlBulkCopy properties
    //With defaults or high values we wouldn't see any notification so 
    // for demoing purposes setting them to be extremely low


    // SqlBulkCopy'nin propertyleri
    // Varsayilan veya yuksek degerlerle hic geri bildirim
    // almayacaktik, o nedenle bu degerleri oldukca kucuk 
    // degerlere kuruyoruz.

    sbc.NotifyAfter = 20;
    sbc.BatchSize = 10;
    //sbc.BulkCopyTimeout = 10000;
    sbc.DestinationTableName = "##SqlBulkSample";

    // Notify in between

    // Arada notification
    sbc.SqlRowsCopied += (sender,e) =>
      {
      Console.WriteLine("-- Copied {0} rows to {1}.", 
        e.RowsCopied, 
        ((SqlBulkCopy)sender).DestinationTableName);
      };

    // Write to server

    // server'a yaz
    sbc.WriteToServer(rdr);

    if (!rdr.IsClosed) { rdr.Close(); }

    cn.Close();

    // Check that it is really written to server. 
    // Just for testing the sample.

    // Server'a hakikaten yazildigini kontrol ediyoruz.
    // Bu sadece ornekte test icin.

    SqlCommand cmdRead = new SqlCommand("select * from ##SqlBulkSample", scn);
    tbl.Load(cmdRead.ExecuteReader());
    scn.Close();
  }

  // Show the data read from SQL server

  // Serverdan okunanlari bir formda goster.
  Form f = new Form();
  DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
  dgv.Location = new Point(0, 0);
  dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  dgv.DataSource = tbl;
  f.Controls.Add(dgv);
  f.ClientSize = new Size(1024, 768);
  f.ShowDialog();
}
```

And also, your software might directly use the VFP data without getting it into MS SQL Server (I don't think you would want to do that but anyway).

HTH